# How can I give an Order in for loop when Creating Objects?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, arraylist

I want to create student objects that have order like student 1, student 2, student 3, ... etc.
And then I want to add my objects into ArrayList.  So I tried this:

```java
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
Student student;
for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    student=new Student();
    students.add(student);
}
```

However, I think the code above does not gives order. It just creates 20 student objects. 
I wonder How could I create 20 student objects by using for loop and give order to these objects.

Comment: These objects that you have created have no content - how are you supposed to sort that?

Comment: in the student class I have a variable id

Comment: A List, by definition, always preserves the order of the elements. This is true not only of ArrayList

Comment: *in the student class I have a variable id* - rather than making us guess what you are doing, please show the code so that we can understand.  When is this `id` being set?

Comment: @lczapski - An ArrayList is a List - also `add` will add at the end of the List

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Have you ever tried using comparator or comparable patterns? If you can also provide the data input to your collections e.g. content to each Student class object of yours. See Collections.sort method and overridden methods from String class for searching and sorting to go into the details.

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering my questions, but I just solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below

```
class Student{
  private int id;
    //remaining member variables 

    Student(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }



}



ArrayList<Student> students=new ArrayList<Student>();
Student student;
for(int  i=0;i<20;i++) {
    student=new Student(i+1);
    students.add(student);
}

//This will print student details;
for(int z=0;z<student.size();z++){
System.out.println("Student "+student[i].getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to java doc of add function -

> ```
> /**
>  * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
>  *
>  * @param e element to be appended to this list
>  * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
>  */
> public boolean add(E e) {
>     ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
>     elementData[size++] = e;
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Which means order is going to be preserved.